# How can I print on a single line inside a nested for loops?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python programming, and this is my first time posting here. I'm trying to make a Python program where I print
`Numbers: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,` to the console all on one line with this code.

```
for i in range(0,1)
       print("Numbers: ")
       for j in range(0,5)
             print(j, end=",")
       print()
```

But I always get

```
Numbers: 
0, 1, 2, 3, 4,
```

What should I do so the output is like this

```
Numbers: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,
```

Comment: Well, you know how to use `end` since you use it in the next `print`? How about `print("Numbers:", end=' ')`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the "end" on your first print(), like this:

```
for i in range(0,1)
       print("Numbers: ", end=": ")
       for j in range(0,5)
             print(j, end=",")
       print()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0,1):
   print("Numbers: ",end='')  
   #print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n')
```

The print() function prints the given object and start pointing to new line , because default value for "end" is '\n' (new line)

```
   for j in range(0,5):
       print(j, end=",")
   print()
```